# Raphael inside div without scrollbars

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to use Raphael on website.
Idea is to have div as background that will be placeholder for Raphael.
I've created blank page with one div and added following code:

```
var r = Raphael("holder", '100%', '100%'),
    targets = r.set(),
    div_w = document.getElementById("holder").clientWidth, //.offsetWidth,
    div_h = document.getElementById("holder").clientWidth; //.offsetHeight;
targets.push(r.rect(10, 10, div_w-20, div_h-20));
targets.attr({
    fill: "#efe",
    stroke: "#fff",
        "stroke-dasharray": "- ",
    opacity: 0.2
});
```

Raphael is drawing, but I get unwanted scrollbars. I can add to body `overflow: hidden` but that's not the point.

My question is: how should I setup Raphael so it will fill fullscreen div without scrollbars.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/Z2L6K/